# Implement toggle switch for theme options in settings API

Tags: php, theme-development, settings-api

I love to work with bootstrap for the forntend part of my projects, but this time I need to create a theme settings page to manage the activation of some template parts of a custom theme. I want to use a switch to enable or disable the features, but I don't know how to implement it in the wordpress way. 
Can anyone provide me a sample of the implementation, I was thinking to use bootstrap but it will be not a pretty choice because wordpress has it's own css rules set to manage the styling of the various inputs and text area on the backend. 
Thanks for the help.

```
<?php

class BSSMenu {

  public function registerSettings()
  {
    add_settings_section(
      'swiper-settings',
      'Swiper slider settings',
      [$this, 'SwiperOptions'],
      $menu_slug
    );

    add_settings_field(
      'swiper-autoload',
      'Auto init slider',
      [$this, 'sliderSettings'],
      $menu_slug,
      'swiper-settings'
    );

    register_setting( 'bs-shortcodes', 'bs-slider' );

  }

  public function initOptionsMenu()
  {
    extract([
      'page_title' => 'Bootstrap Shortcodes - Settings',
      'menu_title' => 'Bootstrap Shortcodes',
      'capability' => 'manage_options',
      'menu_slug' => 'bs-shortcodes',
      'function' => [$this, 'renderOptionsMenu'],
    ]);
    $hook_suffix = add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
    //add_action( 'load-'.$hook_suffix, [$this, 'initMenuScripts'] );
  }


  // public function initMenuScripts()
  // {
  //   wp_enqueue_script('popper-js', PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/popper.min.js', ['jquery'] );
  //   wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', PLUGIN_DIR.'/js/bootstrap.min.js', ['jquery'] );
  //   wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', PLUGIN_DIR.'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  // }

  public function renderOptionsMenu()
  {
    ?>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h1>Bootstrap Shortcodes - Swiper settings</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <form action="options.php" method="POST">
              <!-- Swiper auto init -->
              <?php
                settings_fields('bs-shortcodes');
                do_settings_sections('bs-shortcodes');
                $options = get_option('bs-shortcodes');
              ?>
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="bs-slider" id="customSwitch1" value="0" <?php checked($options['bs-slider'], 1); ?>/>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Auto init swiper</label>
                </div>

              <?php
                submit_button();
              ?>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php
  }

  // public function sliderSettings()
  // {
  //   echo '
  //   <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  //     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="bs-slider" id="customSwitch1" value="'. get_option('bs-slider') .'">
  //     <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Auto init swiper</label>
  //   </div>
  //   ';
  // }

}
?>
```

NB: I'm still doing practice with the settings API, this because I had some difficult to understand how correctly add sections and fields, I'm sorry if there are errors in my code! It use bootstrap 4 but I will rework the code to reflect the default wordpress css backend classes.

Comment: I would look at using the customizer instead of a custom options page if possible. WordPress gives you options for different types of input and this sounds like it just needs a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to implement an options page. You can implement a quick and easy options page via Advanced Custom Fields Pro (find out more here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)

To do things the WordPress way(without the help of plugins), you will want to follow this guide here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/

Once implemented, you should be able to save options via a custom options page. To get the value out, you can use `get_option("YOUR_OPTION_KEY");`.

In regards to styling, you are correct - WordPress does have their own CSS to support administration pages. I would recommend leveraging those instead of using Bootstrap.

Comment: This isn't what I need to know, I already implemented in past an options page, I need some help to implement a toggle switch in an option page. Something like this: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#switches

Comment: @sialfa Apologies, thank you for clarifying. Can you post the code you are using to generate your options page? I can advise you on how to implement it from there.

Comment: I've updated the question, the code I've posted is from an old class where I was implementing some options but it uses bootstrap 4 for the fields class. Feel free to adapt it to reflect the wordpress way to style the inputs and labels. NB: the code is not perfect, this because I'm still working on it to go deeper with the sattings API knowledge and practice!

Comment: From what I can see in your code, you need to un-comment `initMenuScripts` and `add_action( 'load-'.$hook_suffix, [$this, 'initMenuScripts'] );`. If that doesn't work, change the add action to the following: `add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'initMenuScripts'] );`

Comment: I've commented that lines because they will load the bootstrap css and js on the backend and I've opted for the usage of wordpress standard css rules so I don't need them anymore. I was implementing the toggle switch using bootstrap but I was unable to save or retrive the settings

Comment: @sialfa After the line `$options = get_option('bs-shortcodes');`, can you add `print_r($options);`? Then post the output here so we can review what is being saved.